# Generic Singleton Issue In Java

Tags: java, generics

The reason why I want a generic singleton is the following .

I have a class XMLParser , it contains methods to parse a given xml and come out with the POJO for that xml .

```
List<Student> studentList = XMLParser.getInstance().parse(Student.class, xml , String args[]);
```

Now it makes sense to make the XMLParser class a singleton because it doesn't make sense to have more then one objects of XMLParser .

Now the above code statement will correctly give me a unchecked type conversion warning . Because I am unable to properly configure XMLParser to be generic.

Here is where the trouble is happening

```
public class XMLParser<T> {

private static XMLParser reference=null;
String rootNode;
String requiredNode;
List<String> members;
Class<T> targetClass;


private XMLParser()
{

}

public static XMLParser getInstance()
{
    if(reference==null)
        reference= new XMLParser(); // i think I need new XMLParser<T>() here , but how can I transport T here ? 
    return reference;
}
```

As you see it is a basic singleton.  I am unable to do the following

`List<Student> stdent= XMLParser.getInstance<Student.class>().parse(etc etc)`

I am particularly lost as you might notice  .

What should I do ? I just researched and found that static variables cannot use the class's type parameter. Which is what I need for the static variable "reference" . So is there no light at the end of the tunnel here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Having a generic singleton is a bad idea, and even worse if you use it as raw type. By the way, you could have an initializer method where this XML parser is a local variable to the method, thus avoiding the singleton at all.

Comment: Probably a can or worms, but how about a XMLParserFactory which holds an collection of instantiated XMLParsers?  Then XMLParserFactory.getInstance(class).parse (etc, etc);

Comment: Why not simply make XMLParser.parse generic? I don't see why you need your singleton to be generic. Something like: public <T> List<T> parse (Class<T> T, ...)

Comment: What if you need a XMLParser<Student> and a XMLParser<Teacher>? Your implementation only allows one, not matter the generic.

Comment: I'm not even sure you want the XMLParser to be singleton. Did you program it to be thread safe? What if you want several Student.xml-s to be parsed in parallel? By the code I see, before you call the parse method, you should create a new instance of the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
public static <U> XMLParser<U> getInstance()
{
    if(reference==null)
        reference = new XMLParser<U>();
    return (XMLParser<U>)reference;
}
```

And call it like that:

```
XMLParser<Student> parser = XMLParser.<Student>getInstance();
```

Or even directly like that:

```
XMLParser<Student> parser = XMLParser.getInstance();
```

But, as said in the comments, it's not a really good idea to do that.

Comment: thanks florent. indeed everyone is right . it is a wrong idea . If the purpose of a singleton is to have one type of object throughout the application , then I have a flawed requirement perhaps in which I intend to change the parameter type of the class .